# Sharepoint: Is it possible to give users read access to a file but cannot view it in folder?

Tags: sharepoint

Below would illustrate the scenario:

1. I have a folder in Sharepoint
2. it contains several excel files
3. I want users to have read access to all of the files
4. But I don't want these same users to be able to view the files in that folder

Reason: I am accessing the excel files separately via javascript in an application, but I don't want users to actually see the files sitting in the folder (in the event that they "chance" upon that folder.

Greatly appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, giving users read access to files but cannot view files in the folder is not available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get that from a permission level, viewing comes hand-in-hand with read access. But in terms of alternatives, I just read somewhere that I can create a library view to hide the file, then apply a permission level so that that users cannot change personal views. It sounds promising, and I'll try it the soonest I can get a chance.

Comment: Per my test and knowledge, users with read permission can also change view.